# SVG symbol in Safari Shifted while in Chrome and Firefox is looking Great

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, firefox, safari

I have a weird behavior in Safari browser, I have some Inline SVGs and the arrow symbol is shifted to the right only in Safari as you can see in the following links
[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvH9U.jpg)
[Firefox and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIkFc.png)

```html
<svg style="vertical-align:-6.22765642025996pt" width="128pt" height="21pt" viewBox="-1 -1 128 21">
<g font-family="MathFont" font-size="13.5">
    <text y="11.338" x="10.06">⃑</text>
    <text y="13.773"></text>
    <text y="13.773" x="13.611">=</text>
    <text y="13.968" x="27.04"></text>
    <text y="13.773" x="32.702"></text>
    <text y="13.773" x="43.26">−</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="55.929">2</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="62.587">,</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="68.209"></text>
    <text y="13.773" x="88.102">−</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="100.771">2</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="107.429">,</text>
    <text y="13.773" x="113.037">4</text>
    <text y="13.968" x="119.706"></text>
</g>
<g font-family="MathFont" font-size="9.45">
    <text y="8.931" x="79.642"></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your SVGs so the community can give you a better insight into why its happening.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new to the community and don't know much about it, Please see my modified question and thanks for your help

Comment: What inline arrow? The one above the A?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes

Comment: You could always report the problem to the [webkit bugtracker](https://bugs.webkit.org)

Comment: Thank you for help , I will report that problem